# How to turn off automatic line splitting in vim?

Tags: neovim

I mainly use neovim and I found that setting `:set textwidth=0` in ${HOME}/.config/nvim/init.vim has no effect.Textwidth is always 78.

The reason is that other scripts overwrite my settings, I found `textwidth=78` in other scripts:

```sh
$ sudo find ! -path "./home/**" -name "*.vim" ! -path "./proc" ! -path "./run/**" ! -path "./root/**" | xargs grep "textwidth=78"
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/ada.vim:"vim: textwidth=78 nowrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent/ada.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 wrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/changelog.vim:    setlocal textwidth=78
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/help.vim:setlocal formatoptions+=tcroql textwidth=78
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/javascript.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/ada.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 nowrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/occam.vim:setlocal textwidth=78
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/compiler/decada.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 wrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/adacomplete.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 wrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/decada.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 wrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
./usr/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/ada.vim:" vim: textwidth=78 wrap tabstop=8 shiftwidth=3 softtabstop=3 noexpandtab
```

The number of these scripts is a bit large, I don't want to delete them one by one, and I want to avoid modifying scripts that I don't understand as much as possible.

How should I force automatic line breaking off?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at `:help fo-table` as it's actually your `:h 'formatoptions` that is responsible to wrap the lines when typing in insert mode, see the `t` letter.

You can remove the letter with:

```
set formatoptions-=t
```

You can identify where an option is set with the `:h :verbose` command:

```
:verbose set tw?
  textwidth=80
        Last set from ~/.config/.vim/vimrc line 131
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: I think the `c`  letter is important as well.